# PHP script sent to email not displaying $message variable

Tags: php, contact-form

I am new to PHP, but, I have a simple contact form that is sending to my email. Everything works as expected except the `$message` variable is not displaying.

The php is processing the request and sending the website viewer to the thank you page, viewer is also getting confirmation email, and I am receiving the email with all requested variables except the `$message` data.

The variables are consolidated into `$totalmessage` due to the `mail()` function limits.

As I said, I am new to php, but appreciate your help.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

    $to = "me@mywebsite.com";
    $subject = "Inquiry";
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;

    if (isset($_POST['interest']) && $_POST['interest']!= 'none'){ 

        if (is_array($_POST['interest'])){ 
            $interest = implode(" ", $_POST['interest']); // format your array for use 
        } else { 
            $interest = $_POST['interest']; // no array -> print single value 
        } 
    } 
    $method = $_REQUEST['method' ] ;
    $message = $_GET['message'] ;
    $totalmessage = "
        Name:       $name \n
        Email:      $email \n
        Phone:      $phone \n
        Interest:           $interest \n
        Method:     $method \n 
        Message:             $message \n ";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $totalmessage, $headers);
    if($sent)
        header( "Location: /thankyou.html" );
    else
        print "We encountered an error sending your mail";
?>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="row">
    <br><label for="message"> Message:</label><br/>
    <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Email Output:**

```
            Name:           bob

            Email:          bob@gmail.com

            Phone:          123-456-7890

            Interest:       research

            Method:         email

            Message:                               <===should have message text
```

Comment: We don't see your form, but I'm guessing the message is in `$_POST['message']`, not passed through the URL in `$_GET`.

Comment: Do you know the differences between `$_REQUEST` `$_POST` and `$_GET`?

Comment: I had tried using REQUEST as seen in other tips, but this was not working. Yes, the form is using POST. I changed the method to POST in the php and it is working beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt use the GET variable for sending the message.
The URL can only send 255 letters! So the best is to send it with POST.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?action=send">
<textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

and in ur php:

```
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$message = $_GET['message'] ;` to `$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;` or `$message = $_POST['message'] ;` for now, and let us know if this works.

PHP `$_REQUEST` includes everything under the `$_GET` and `$_POST` but POST and GET do not share parameters. Since it seems like everything else you've got is being passed by POST, it would make sense that the message is set up to be passed by POST as well.

Read up on differences between POST and GET [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340704/get-vs-post-in-html-forms).

In short, use GET when you want to get data from a DB or your data model (should not execute anything that changes any states of anything).

Use POST when you want to change your data model, or if you want to execute something (like in this case, execute an emailer script).

Comment: the $_REQUEST method did not work, so was changed to $_GET (which did not work and was left over from that attempt). Changed to $message = $_POST['message'] ; and it works wonderfully! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default the `$_REQUEST` variable contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

The `$_GET` variable is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.

The `$_POST` variable is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

You probably have got the message through a `form` posted from an other page, or this one, and then you want to do:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

instead of the get.

Comment: the $_REQUEST method did not work, so was changed to $_GET (which did not work and was left over from that attempt). Changed to $message = $_POST['message'] ; and it works wonderfully! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be consistent with your POST / GET / REQUEST arrays. What is the Method that your form is using? Whatever that is, use the same in your form processing code.
For instance, if your form says: `<form method="POST">` then your backend code should grab all of its values from the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$message =$_REQUEST['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Mailsend supposely starts the sending action. In $subject I suggest a text area form for that or else you'll only get the word inquiry in every message.

Can you try?

```
  $to = "me@mywebsite.com";
    $subject = "Inquiry";
    $name = $_POST['name'] ;
    $email = $_POST['email'] ;
    $phone = $_POST['phone'] ; 

$mailsend = mail ('$to', '$subject',"Name: $name\r\nEmail: $emial\r\nPhone: $phone\r\n" );

if ($mailsend) {
    echo "Hello $name . Lorem ipsum est un divagat de pleure malucate";}

else {
    echo "ERROR sending";}
```